# Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Sherlock.Light'

Tags: android, xml

```
<style name="android:style/Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Im getting the error that written at the topic and I don't understand why. The min sdk is defined as 13. Please HELP!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Sherlock` parent style, which is defined by `@style/`, and not this one that you have  from android library, which is called by `@android:style` (same for `color`, `drawable`, etc), as follows:

```
<style ... parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
```

Sometimes, this above will not work. Another solution is [to call the parent without `@style/` prefix](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) as:

```
<style ... parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
```

Then, when you call your custom style, it might be better to use a name like this:

```
<style name="ThemeTransparent" ... >
```

which will be attached to the application (or an activity) in the manifest file with:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ThemeTransparent" >
```

Comment: <style name="ThemeTransparent" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">

It's still doing the same error.

Comment: You have to clean (*in Eclipse: Project > Clean > Select your project and Clean it*) and rebuild the project when you customize the style with Sherlock, @ShmulikChicvashvili. After this, you just have to close the file.

Comment: I cleaned and rebuild few times. What file do I need to close?

Comment: I meant `styles.xml`, @ShmulikChicvashvili. But it's just to inform you that every saved on this file needs to be followed by a cleaning of your project, and when you don't change it, close it.. Anyway, you can keep it opened, that's not a big deal.

Comment: Oh okay, but its till aint working. still getting the same error :(

Comment: Try the other solution, @ShmulikChicvashvili. I hope this work. Don't forget to clean again ;)

Comment: This is weird, @ShmulikChicvashvili, make sure the project has the right library, also change all the styles.xml. Personally, Sherlock is added and imported in my workplace and I use `@style/...`, I have no errors...